# Check that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}$ is continuous or not.

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Define $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ by

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}$$

Check that $f$ is continuous or not.

Attempt: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}\\
=\lim\int_{0}^{1}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}$$
Now, Putting $x=\sin\theta$, then $\mathrm dx=\cos\theta\mathrm d\theta$, therefore integral reduces to

$$\lim\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)^{n-1}\cos\theta\mathrm d\theta\\
=\lim\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2\theta\cos^n\theta\mathrm d\theta$$

Now from here the result will depend on $n$ i.e. $n=2m,n=2m+1$
In these two cases the result will be different, Hence $f$ is not continuous.

am I right? Different approaches are invited. Thank you.

Comment: How did you jump from the summation to the integral? What is the limit over?

Comment: Hint: for $x \in [0,1], 1 - x^2 \in [0,1]$. Recall the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: This is a geometric series. For $x = 0$ it's especially easy.

Comment: @copper.hat integration is generalisation of summation, but , somthing is wrong in my solution

Comment: That is nice as a bedtime story, but it won't fly in math. class.

Comment: @HansEngler for $x=0$ this will be $0$, i'm not getting your hint

Comment: You can write down an explicit formula for $f$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and the values for $x=0,1$ are immediate. Check continuity of the result. (As an aside, you can't just move from summation to integration with a friendly wave and the addition of $\lim$!)

Answer (score 2):

To see that the series is geometric, hold x constant, compute $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}=\frac {x^2(1-x^2)^n}{x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}}=1-x^2$, which you can see is independant of $n$.  At $x=0$, all your terms are trivially 0.  At  $x=1$, the first term is 1 (if you accept $0^0=1$ as the set theorists would have it!) and all the others are 0, so $f(1)=0$. Between them,  $1-x^2<1$, so it converges. In between,  you have the formula for the sum of a geometric series is $\frac {a_1}{1-r}=\frac {x^2}{1-(1-x^2)}=1$.

So,  for $x\in (0,1)$,  $f(x)=1$, so you have one jump discontinuity at 0

(editted as per comments)

Comment: There is no discontinuity at $x=1$. We have $f=1_{(0,1]}$.

Comment: @copper.hat At $x=1$ the function is $0$, which is a jump down from 1....

Comment: Well, it is a little ambiguous, but for $n=1$ I interpreted $x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}$ as $x^2$.

Comment: Oh, true.  I'll edit to fix.

Comment: Well, it falls under ambiguous, but for $x=0$ there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I'm in the $0^0=1$ camp,  but yeah,  there is argument there

Answer (score 1):

The series converges pointwise to $f$ on $[0,1]$. Note that $f(0)=0$.

By the $M$-Test,  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }x^2(1-x^2)^{n}$ converges uniformly on $[a,1];\ a\neq 0$ and so is continuous there.

But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a^2(1-a^2)^{n}=a^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(1-a^2)^{n}=\frac{a^{2}}{1-(1-a^{2})}=1$ and since this is true for all $0<a<1$ $f$ is not contiuous at $x=0$.